# Truncate text to fit user control

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm building a sort of note/task manager app. When I add a new note it looks like this.[image]

But if I enter too much text it looks like this.
[image]

What I want to achieve is truncate the label text the way it will fit into the user control and look like the following.[image]

I don't have a clue of how to do this, unfortunately.

Comment: Set the AutoEllipsis property? Unless you're drawing the text yourself... -- Remember to anchor the Label properly, since it cannot auto-size

Answer (score 0):

Here is an extension method I wrote for one of my projects to address the issue you are describing.
 The method cuts the text based on the condition you pass as arguments.
 Please refer to the XML documentation for an explanation of each argument.
 You can cut the long text based on the length, and you can also cut it without breaking a word by setting the "grace" with `maxWordCharsCount`.

The method will truncate the text and append three dots at the end (you can customize it by passing a different text ending to the `endOfString` argument), and you can also display the full text in the tooltip of the label:

```
public static class ExtentionMethods
{
    /// <summary>
    /// cut`s the string in order to short it when showing on GUI in limited space
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="theString"> current string </param>
    /// <param name="maxCharsCount"> the max length of the shrinked string</param>
    /// <param name="breakWork"> boolean to break or not to break work</param>
    /// <param name="maxWordCharsCount">when we need to cut in a middle of a word we will try to avoid it and counting more maxWordCharsCount times</param>
    /// <param name="endOfString">the string to add in the end of the string, defult is '...'</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string CutText(this string theString, int maxCharsCount, bool breakWork = false, int maxWordCharsCount = 10, string endOfString = "...")
    {
        var result = "";
        if (breakWork)
        {
            if (maxCharsCount < theString.Length)
                result = theString.Substring(0, maxCharsCount - endOfString.Length) + endOfString;
            else
                return theString;
        }
        else
        {

            if (maxCharsCount > theString.Length)
                return theString;

            var counter = 0;
            var maxwordcounter = 0;
            var stop = maxCharsCount - endOfString.Length;
            foreach (var line in theString)
            {
                if (counter <= stop)
                {
                    result += line;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (line.ToString() == " ")
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (maxwordcounter >= maxWordCharsCount)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result += line;
                    }

                    maxwordcounter++;
                }
                counter++;
            }

            result += endOfString;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

**Implementation:**

```
string str = "This is a very long task description This is a very long task description This is a very long task description";
label1.Text = str.CutText(30);
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: AutoEllipsis property Jimi advised works just fine I guess. Given method doesn't seem to involve user control size...